# How to get the microsoft teams channel connected folder url in graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

How to get the channel connected folder URL in SharePoint.Is there any way to find the drive id of the channel connected folder URL using channel id?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is away. I am not sure I understand your question, but I think I know enough to answer this question. As we know every channel in the Microsoft Team has its own folder in the Sharepoint. What I have been doing in my app is getting the drive ID of those folders and uploading lots of files on those folders of channels using ***Microsoft graph API***.

Unfortunately, you need a team or groupId on this endpoint. It will give you id of the general folder and also drive the Id of that channel. /groups/{id}/drive/items/root:/General.
Once you find the drive Id you could do this to go to a specific file on the ChannelFolder
/drives/{DriveId}/root:/General:/children. I believe, You want to use ChannelId to get the driveId but something tells me that you already have a groupId so you could use groupId to go to any channel and any drive Id of that channel.

Comment: yeah, thanks, it's working but when I rename my channel name. it won't work. That's why I asked the channel id based retrieving process.

Comment: Yea, I researched a bit to see if we can get files with ChannelId. I did not see any. If I were you, I would pass the name of the channel as a parameter so no matter what you change the channel name to, it will then take the new name that was read..and send it with the api.  As of right now looks like you have to give the api the path "name" to retrieve files. I will update you if I figure out a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the metadata for the location of where the files of a channel are stored by sending the following request:

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/filesFolder
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more details.

It is also possible to get an array of drive items (folders) attached to a given channel by requesting the following:

```
GET /groups/${groupId}/drive/root/children
```

You may also find these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) quite useful.